# Can`t execute a query with Restrictions.sqlRestriction

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, postgresql

Hy I write a query and I can execute in Postgres, there works fine, but when I want to execute with Restrictions.sqlRestriction(query) it gives syntax error.
This is what I try to do

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("SELECT * FROM job JOIN job_applications as j ON id=id_job WHERE id=(SELECT id_job FROM (SELECT id_job,COUNT (id_job_seeker) FROM job_applications GROUP BY id_job) AS foo WHERE COUNT = "+ dataTableFilter.sSearch[index]+")"));
```

and gives this

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc-dispatcher] in
>   context with path [/XYX] threw exception [Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   syntax error at or near "SELECT"   Position: 287  at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)

I looked on the Internet but I don`t really understand how should I do it.Any suggestion how should I transform my query to be executable?

Comment: You want to add a restriction into query, which is the query? 
btw since You want to use whole sql query why bother to use criteria with restrictions ?

Comment: This is the query:
SELECT * FROM job JOIN job_applications as j ON id=id_job WHERE id=(SELECT id_job FROM (SELECT id_job,COUNT (id_job_seeker) FROM job_applications GROUP BY id_job) AS foo WHERE COUNT = x )
and I collect all querys from filter inputs in criteria and I execute the criteria and the result will show in my JqueryDatatable.